# Kubernetes POD restarting

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running GKE cluster with two node pool.

1st node pool: 1 node (No auto scaling)(4 vCPU, 16 GB RAM)

2nd node pool: 1 node (Auto scaling to 2 node) (1 vCPU, 3.75 GB RAM)

here : kubectl top node

[image]

we started cluster with a single node running Elasticsearch, Redis, RabbitMQ and all micro service on single node. we can not add more node in 1st node pool as it will be wasting of resources. 1st node can satisfy all resource requirements.

We are facing POD restarting for only one microservice.

[image]

core service pod is only restarting. when tried to `describe pod` it's `ERROR 137 terminated`.

In GKE stack drive graph `Memory` and `CPU` is not reaching to limit.

All pods in cluster utilization

[image]

In cluster log I have found this warning :

```
0/3 nodes are available: 3 Insufficient CPU.
```

but here it's 3 nodes total CPU around 6 vCPU which is more than enough.

Also this error

```
Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 3383411 (python3) score 2046 or sacrifice child Killed process 3384902 (python3) total-vm:14356kB, anon-rss:5688kB, file-rss:4572kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

**EDIT : 1**

```
Name:           test-core-7fc8bbcb4c-vrbtw
Namespace:      default
Priority:       0
Node:           gke-test-cluster-highmem-pool-gen2-f2743e02-msv2/10.128.0.7
Start Time:     Fri, 17 Jan 2020 19:59:54 +0530
Labels:         app=test-core
                pod-template-hash=7fc8bbcb4c
                tier=frontend
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Running
IP:             10.40.0.41
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/test-core-7fc8bbcb4c
Containers:
  test-core:
    Container ID:   docker://0cc49c15ed852e99361590ee421a9193e10e7740b7373450174f549e9ba1d7b5
    Image:          gcr.io/test-production/core/production:fc30db4
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://gcr.io/test-production/core/production@sha256:b5dsd03b57sdfsa6035ff5ba9735984c3aa714bb4c9bb92f998ce0392ae31d055fe
    Ports:          9595/TCP, 443/TCP
    Host Ports:     0/TCP, 0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sun, 19 Jan 2020 14:54:52 +0530
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    137
      Started:      Sun, 19 Jan 2020 07:36:42 +0530
      Finished:     Sun, 19 Jan 2020 14:54:51 +0530
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  7
    Limits:
      cpu:     990m
      memory:  1Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:      200m
      memory:   128Mi
    Liveness:   http-get http://:9595/k8/liveness delay=25s timeout=5s period=5s #success=1 #failure=30
    Readiness:  http-get http://:9595/k8/readiness delay=25s timeout=8s period=5s #success=1 #failure=30
    Environment Variables from:
      test-secret             Secret     Optional: false
      core-staging-configmap  ConfigMap  Optional: false
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-hcz6d:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-hcz6d
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

Please help.
Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Are you setting resource limits in the pod configurations?

Comment: @wobr Yes. also i have seen pod rediness, liveness failing sometimes.

Comment: it is possible docker image linux os killing python application process ?

Comment: Commands like `kubectl` usually output text, not images.  Can you replace these PNG files with the actual text these commands are producing?  It's also generally much more useful to provide application source code or YAML artifacts that describe how to reproduce the situation, and not just diagnostics that show a problem.

Comment: could you update your post and show us the full output of `kuberentes describe pod <that_pod_name>` (remove the information you don't want to share, and this output: `kubernetes get events`?

Comment: @BMW i have updated post. thankyou

Comment: Check your livenes probes. Could be, that livenes probe is failing, and so Kuberenetes shuts POD down.

Comment: @GintsGints I had similar doubt for probe liveness, rediness. that is the issue with some pod only but if we consider update i have did in question there is no event of failing probe. otherwise failing probe events may occur.

Comment: Have a look at the Kubernetes best practices: Resource requests and limits[1]: "Because there is no way to throttle memory usage, if a container goes past its memory limit it will be terminated." And as you can see, you already have an error pointing to this: `Memory cgroup out of memory`. Try to increase memory limits and check how it runs. [1]: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-resource-requests-and-limits

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza thankyou so much for writing answer. i have seen one weird behavior i have set memory limit to 1 GB but pod restarting at 400-500 MB in event i am getting liveness rediness failing.

Comment: Do you still have the same errors as before?

Comment: now this is error is gone but pod is restarting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application running in the pod may be consuming more memory than the specified limits. You can docker exec / kubectl exec into the container and monitor the applications using top. But from perspective of managing the whole cluster, we do it using cadvisor (which is part of Kubelet) + Heapster. But now Heapster is replaced by kube-metric server (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/resource-usage-monitoring)